# Creating new layer based on existing layer Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, layers, weighted-overlay

I have many layers consist of many parameters. I want to create a new layer called 'Reforestation Priority Area' based on weighting given to existing layers. Is there any way to do that?

The code is below:

```
var countries = Indonesia

var Nama_Provinsi = ['Kalimantan Selatan'] 
var geometry = countries.filter(ee.Filter.inList('NAME_1', Nama_Provinsi));
var area1 = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry);

var image = ee.Image('WCMC/biomass_carbon_density/v1_0/2010');

Map.addLayer(
    image.clip(area1), {
      min: 1,
      max: 180,
      palette: ['d9f0a3', 'addd8e', '78c679', '41ab5d', '238443', '005a32']
    },
    'carbon_tonnes_per_ha');
    
var dataset = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2020_v1_8');
var treeCoverVisParam = {
  bands: ['treecover2000'],
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  palette: ['black', 'green']
};
Map.addLayer(dataset.clip(area1), treeCoverVisParam, 'tree cover');

var treeLossVisParam = {
  bands: ['lossyear'],
  min: 0,
  max: 18,
  palette: ['yellow', 'red']
};
Map.addLayer(dataset.clip(area1), treeLossVisParam, 'tree loss year')

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13Q1')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'));
var evi = dataset.select('EVI');
var eviVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 8000.0,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.setCenter(116, -3, 8);

var table_bound = function(image){
  return image.clip(area1);
};
var eviclipped = evi.map(table_bound)

Map.addLayer(eviclipped, eviVis, 'EVI2020');

var dataset = ee.Image("COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019")
.select('discrete_classification');

Map.setCenter(116, -3, 8);

Map.addLayer(dataset.clip(area1), {}, "Land Cover");

//displaying the data in interactive map
Map.addLayer(image.clip(area1), {min:0, max: 300, 
palette: ['90EE90','FFFF00','FF0000']}, 'Raw SRTM'); //Light green, yellow, red

//display hillshading and slope
var hillshade = ee.Terrain.hillshade(image);
Map.addLayer(hillshade.clip(area1), {min:150, max:255,}, 'Hillshade', false);
print(hillshade);

var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(image);
Map.addLayer(slope.clip(area1), {min:0, max:20, pallete: ['FFFFFF']},'Slope', false);
print(slope);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the weighting is linear against some thresholds, then you can probably do something like this:

```
// Binary thresholds
var result = ee.Image().int()
   .expression("term1 * 0.3 + term2 * 0.5 + term3 * 0.1", {
       term1: slope.lt(3),
       term2: evi.gt(0.6),
       term3: dataset.eq(10)
   })
```

If the terms are continuous instead, then just leave off the comparisons and multiply by whatever weighting factors directly.